# How to create joomla 2.5 component?

Tags: php, joomla, joomla-component

I'm already use joomla component creating application . But that is not a best way , then i think to learn it. please send best tutorial for that .    :)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is the general documentation page [for developing Joomla! Components](http://docs.joomla.org/Category%3aComponent_Development).

The Joomla! Doc's [tutorial specifically for components in 2.5](http://docs.joomla.org/Developing_a_Model-View-Controller_%28MVC%29_Component_for_Joomla!2.5_-_Part_01) is this one.

The list of Joomla! Doc's for all versions of Joomla! can be found on [this page](http://docs.joomla.org/Developing_a_Model-View-Controller_Component).

*The one referenced to by @pikk is for Joomla! 1.5.*

*The page referenced to by @chandresh is a Joomla forum question from 2006 for Joomla 1.0.*